# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass missing method

Tags: .net, powershell, methods, outlook, namespaces

I'm currently working with PowerShell and the Outlook namespace to move emails between folders, but as soon as I want to start my script I get the error:

> Method error, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass does not contain a method called "Folders".

I'm calling the namespace like this:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$MAPI = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

The weird thing is that it worked before, but suddenly it doesn't anymore.
PowerShell itself even shows me the command via IntelliSense:

[image: Powershell command]